# selecting runtime labels

Tags: vb.net, runtime, label

I'm writing a plastic card printing program in VB.NET. The main form is to design the card.

I create labels at runtime into a Panel control, the user can move, edit, resize etc. while it is the active control. When a few labels are created I can't change the selected label to edit.

I've tried adding a combobox with a list of the controls as they are created and use a for loop to find the control and make it the active control but this is not really user friendly.

Is there a cleverer way to use the mouse to select another label in the Panel?

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: Can you use the MouseUp event?

Comment: no, there's no event handler as the label is created at runtime. Once it is selected or has the focus everything works.

Comment: You can easily create event handlers at run-time. Just use `AddHandler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a panel to a form and try this:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
      Dim lbl As New Label
      AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf lbl_Click
      Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
      lbl.Top = 30 * i
      lbl.Text = "Hello!"
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub lbl_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    lbl.Font = New Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Clicking on a label should change the appearance of the label.

Answer (score 0):

I like SSS's answer, but I'd avoid creating the `Private Sub` event handler and just use an in-line lambda instead:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 4
  Dim lbl As New Label
  AddHandler lbl.Click,
    Sub (s, e)
        lbl.Font = New Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12)
    End Sub
  Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
  lbl.Top = 30 * i
  lbl.Text = "Hello!"
Next
```

Comment: I copied your code, never heard of a lambda, it causes syntax errors thinks it's a sub and I'm using 2008.

Comment: that didn't work. I've never used these before so I could be overlooking something.

Comment: @Brix - It won't work on 2008. You need 2012. Sorry. I did test the code before posting it. `Sub (s, e)` works in .NET 4.0.